# Apply class to parent UL if child LI contains specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a side menu that will list all pages in the relative section. I pretty much have this sorted apart from 1 small thing. We have 2 levels of dropdowns meaning there are an awful lot of links.

The LI that is active will have the class of `.current_page_item`. I'm trying to work out a way of saying:
If the UL has a child LI containing `.current_page_item` class then apply `.side_open` class to the UL.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Demo 1
    <ul>
      <li class="current_page_item">Demo 11</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Demo 2
    <ul>
      <li>Demo 21</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Demo 3
    <ul>
      <li>Demo 31</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Demo 4
    <ul>
      <li>Demo 41</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If anyone has any ideas on how this can be done your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show your code that have you tried yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to style the direct parent if the `li` is selected.
(Comment me if I'm wrong)

So, the following should be what you want to achieve:
(Done with some Javascript)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul>li>ul>li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('current_page_item')) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('side_open');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.side_open {
  background: #ddd;
}

.current_page_item {
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Demo 1
    <ul>
      <li class="current_page_item">Demo 11</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Demo 2
    <ul>
      <li>Demo 21</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Demo 3
    <ul>
      <li>Demo 31</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Demo 4
    <ul>
      <li>Demo 41</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.parentElement` property to access `li`'s `ul`.

```js
const linksArray = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')];

linksArray.forEach(link => {
  link.onclick = function() {
    linksArray.forEach(link => link.classList.remove('current_page_item'))
    this.classList.add('current_page_item')
    this.parentElement.classList.add('side_open')
  }
})
```

```css
.current_page_item {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.side_open:before {
  content: 'I have side open class';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jquery. It's very simple, using each loop, traverse and check for class in each LI and add `.side_open` class in it's parent if that li has `.current_page_item` class.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.main_ul>li>ul.sub_ul>li').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('current_page_item')){
      $(this).parent().addClass('side_open');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.side_open {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main_ul">
  <li class="main_li">Demo 1
    <ul class="sub_ul">
      <li class="current_page_item">Demo 11</li>
      <li class="current_page_item">Demo 12</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="main_li">Demo 2
    <ul class="sub_ul">
      <li>Demo 21</li>
      <li>Demo 22</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="main_li">Demo 3
    <ul class="sub_ul">
      <li>Demo 31</li>
      <li>Demo 32</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="main_li">Demo 4
    <ul class="sub_ul">
      <li>Demo 41</li>
      <li>Demo 42</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```